# How to import the Excel (block coordinates) in Autocad 2016 through C# .net API?

Tags: .net, autocad, autocad-plugin

I am trying to import the Excel sheet in that we have block attributes. My requirement to import the sheet through command and then my C# code will fetch the block attributes values through sheet and design the block in Autocad save that drawing on system.

```
static public void InsertingABlock(System.Data.DataTable dt)
            {
                double  _xCoord =0;
                double _yCoord = 0;
                double _zCoord = 0;


                // Get the current database and start a transaction
                Database acCurDb;
                acCurDb = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Database;

                using (Transaction acTrans = acCurDb.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
                {
                    // Open the Block table for read
                    BlockTable acBlkTbl;
                    acBlkTbl = acTrans.GetObject(acCurDb.BlockTableId, OpenMode.ForRead) as BlockTable;

                    ObjectId blkRecId = ObjectId.Null;

                    if (!acBlkTbl.Has("CircleBlock1"))
                    {
                        using (BlockTableRecord acBlkTblRec = new BlockTableRecord())
                        {
                            acBlkTblRec.Name = "CircleBlock";
                            //= Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["columnname"]);
                            // Set the insertion point for the block
                            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                            {
                                DataRow row = dt.Rows[0];

                                _xCoord = double.Parse(row["Position X"].ToString());
                                _yCoord = double.Parse(row["Position Y"].ToString());
                                _zCoord = double.Parse(row["Position Z"].ToString());
                            }
                            acBlkTblRec.Origin = new Point3d(_xCoord, _yCoord, _zCoord);
                            // Add a circle to the block
                            using (Circle acCirc = new Circle())
                            {
                                acCirc.Center = new Point3d(800, 300, 0);
                                acCirc.Radius = 10;
                                acBlkTblRec.AppendEntity(acCirc);
                                acBlkTbl.UpgradeOpen();
                                acBlkTbl.Add(acBlkTblRec);
                                acTrans.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(acBlkTblRec, true);
                            }
                            blkRecId = acBlkTblRec.Id;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        blkRecId = acBlkTbl["CircleBlock"];
                    }
                    // Insert the block into the current space
                    if (blkRecId != ObjectId.Null)
                    {
                        using (BlockReference acBlkRef = new BlockReference(new Point3d(0, 0, 0), blkRecId))
                        {
                            BlockTableRecord acCurSpaceBlkTblRec;
                            acCurSpaceBlkTblRec = acTrans.GetObject(acCurDb.CurrentSpaceId, OpenMode.ForWrite) as BlockTableRecord;
                            acCurSpaceBlkTblRec.AppendEntity(acBlkRef);
                            acTrans.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(acBlkRef, true);
                        }
                    }
                    // Save the new object to the database
                    acTrans.Commit();
                    // Dispose of the transaction
                }
            }
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Readers will generally ask to see what research you have, or what code you are trying. If you have neither then it is too early to ask a question.

Comment: You might be reinventing the wheel here. Applications like CADPower and GeoTools have a rich set of features for importing text based content and also working with blocks with attributes.